# Why won't this code-behind binding work?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, code-behind

Taking from [this blog post](http://lexa.tatalata.com/transform-bitmap-in-wpf/), I implemented those 2 classes and tried the XAML, and it works. I would like to make a custom control that does the same, so I wrote this. However, it does not recolor the image. It only produces the uncolored image. I assume that I am doing something wrong with the binding, but I am not sure.

EDIT: Changed code to be a SSCCE

```
public class ColorableImage : Image
{
    // Used by the converter to color the source
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;

    static ColorableImage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorableImage)));

        ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ColorPropertyChanged)));
    }

    private static void ColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorableImage castedSender = (ColorableImage)sender;
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = castedSender.Source;
        Color color = castedSender.Color;
        Binding binding = new Binding("Source")
        {
            Source = img,
            Converter = new HighlightImageConverter(),
            ConverterParameter = color
        };
        castedSender.SetBinding(ColorableImage.SourceProperty, binding);
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Well it is a bit strange. When Source property changes you change OriginalImage. And using the binding the Source changes when OriginalImage changes. Looks a bit like an infinit loop. But in this case there would be a stack overflow exception.

Comment: Yes - the property used to be called ColorOverlay and I forgot to change that string along with it. Thanks for reminding me. I will look into creating another handler for Color instead of a setter

Comment: If you don't want to loose time writing DP code you could youse some snippets. I use the ones from Dr WPF http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/17/my-wpf-code-snippets/

Comment: I had an infinite loop at first, because I tried to put the binding in both callbacks, which makes one callback refer to the other (since one changes the source and the other changes the color). However, the color only refers to the source, so it goes sourcechanged -> colorchanged -> sourcechanged. Either way, I shortened my code in the post, so the problem should be easier to attack now.

Comment: I've just tested your code with <local:ColorableImage Source="wmv.png" Color="Red"/> and it looks like it works. It colors parts of the picture in red.

Comment: It appears to be working... I think the problem was that I was using an image that was all black and alpha, so color overlay on pure black just makes black, which look like no change. I may change the coloring algorithm, but the class itself looks like it's working. Thanks for your help.